# Facebook Social Plugins / Comments in IOS Application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I have done a fair amount of searching on this topic the last few weeks, and tried multiple answers I've found here that either don't work with the new IOS SDK or don't apply.    So i hope this is not seen as a repeat question...

We are developing an IOS application that uses the Facebook login / IOS SDK for logging into the application.   The user then creates some content that is displayed in the application for others to see.   The content can also be viewed on the web  outside the application in a browser.   The hope is to utilize Facebook comments social plugin both in the application and on the site.

I can easily add a comments social plugin to the generated web page, but would like the comments to be available in a UIWebView inside the application as well.   The issue is in the application, the user has already logged into Facebook in the application but when I show the comments portion of the posting, it asks the user to log back in.

I would like to avoid this by somehow passing the access token or session from the IOS SDK to the Javascript.    I can successfully pass the access token to a PHP script on our server and make calls like $facebook->getUser() and etc, but can't seem to prevent the duplicate login in the comments social plugin, even when call the plugin from the PHP script I wrote below.

Any help would be great with examples.

Thanks!  Andy P

```
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");


$config = array();
$config['appId'] = $_POST["appId"];
$config['secret'] = $_POST["secret"];
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$config['cookie'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setAccessToken($_POST["accessToken"]);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
// note, I always get back a good $user here when I pass the accessToken from SDK
?>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $_POST["appId"]?>',                        // App ID     from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//www.awplabs.com/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true,                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
      cookie : true,
      oauth:true
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));    


</script>

<?php 
echo "<div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"https://awplabs.com/" . $_POST["pageId"] . "\" data-width=\"480\" data-num-posts=\"20\"></div>"
?>

</body>
```